# XML to table format. I get only one table. I need to display two tables, how to do it?

Tags: php, xml, html-table

I get only one table. I need to display two tables, how to do it?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
  <book> 
    <title>Heart of a Dog</title>
    <author>Mikhail Bulgakov</author>
  </book>
  <book> 
    <title>Postmortem</title>
    <author>Patricia Cornwell</author>
  </book>
</books>
```

Maybe the wrong **foreach loop** construct?

```php
 <?php
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('books.xml');
 foreach ($xml as $x) {
    $title = $x->title;
    $author = $x->author;
 }
 ?>

<table width="200" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo "Title: ".$title; ?></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><?php echo "Author: ".$author; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: two rows or two tables?

Comment: What do you mean by two tables? Please make an edit in your question and add the desired output.

Comment: I think you need to display two rows and it's pointless having two tables for displaying data of two books in XML separately.

Comment: Example: Shows a table: [link](http://kelioniupasaulis.lt/examples/example_xml_10/table.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to your output**
Your code is correct, except just you need to put your Table inside your loop and generate table for each book.

```
<?php
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('books.xml');
 foreach ($xml as $x) {
    $title = $x->title;
    $author = $x->author;
    ?>
    <table style="margin-top:10px;" width="200" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo "Title: ".$title; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo "Author: ".$author; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Tables bruh he/she said Tables

Comment: now i think match with output he/she intended, Update if any

Comment: Another issue where the screw tag <p> The vertical space between the tables?

Comment: put css ...use padding and margins.I have put style as margin-top in above code. similarly you can put style to your <tr> <td> <p> anything. All about styling, please see the css